# How to hide jenkins pipeline stage view log button?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Use 'set +x' to hide the console log, how to hide stage view log on Web UI or hide the log button?
[Stage View UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7s11.png)

Comment: could you be more specific? What do you want to obtain exactly? Did you try anything?

Comment: I use shell script with sensitive message in pipeline, and hide the console logs with 'set +x' command. But I can't hide the logs on stage view UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sensitive data (username, password,...) you could use jenkins credentials:

- you add credentials for your sensitive data
- you can use them in your **Jenkinsfile** like this:

Jenkinsfile:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'secret_user', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
    sh "echo $USERNAME $PASSWORD"
}
```

then **Jenkins** is smart enough to replace that with ******* in your log files.

more information here: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

Comment: Thank you for that. I use ```wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[password: 'password', var: 'SECRET']]]) { }``` to hide sensitive data in logs like ******. But  MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper or Credentials can not hide pipeline stage view logs in build history on project main page.

Comment: I'v replaced  MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper with  withCredentials(). The sensitive data in Shell Script Logs was replace to $PASSWORD. It's worked. Thank you.